# Using groovy.util.AntBuilder from java

Tags: java, ant, groovy

In groovy the groovy.util.AntBuilder can be used to eg. unzip a file into a folder:

```
  AntBuilder ant = new AntBuilder();
  ant.unzip(src: file.getPath(), dest: outputFolder.getPath());
```

Now I would like to do the same but from java. Its not possible to call unzip directly. I assume thats what the invokeMethod is for:

```
  AntBuilder ant = new AntBuilder();
  String[] args = new String[4];
  args[0] = "src";
  args[1] = file.getPath();
  args[2] = "dest";
  args[3] = outputFolder.getPath();
  ant.invokeMethod("unzip", args);
```

the above gives:

```
 No signature of method: groovy.util.AntBuilder.unzip() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values:
```

Any ideas?

I have tried to google docs/examples for using the AntBuilder from java, but I have only found examples where its used from groovy.

Comment: ant.unzip takes a Map as a parameter. have you tried that?

Comment: Did my solution below work for you?

Answer (score 4):

Right, got to a computer and gave it a go:

Given this Java class:

```
import groovy.util.AntBuilder ;
import java.io.File ;
import java.util.HashMap ;

public class Test {
  public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
    if( args.length != 2 ) {
      System.err.println( "Need 2 args.  Input zip file and output folder" ) ;
      System.exit( 1 ) ;
    }
    final File file = new File( args[ 0 ] ) ;
    final File outputFolder = new File( args[ 1 ] ) ;
    AntBuilder ant = new AntBuilder() ;
    ant.invokeMethod( "unzip", new HashMap() {{
      put( "src", file.getPath() ) ;
      put( "dest", outputFolder.getPath() ) ;
    }} ) ;
  }
}
```

You can then compile it with:

```
javac -cp $GROOVY_HOME/embeddable/groovy-all-2.0.5.jar Test.java
```

And then run:

```
java -cp $GROOVY_HOME/lib/*:. Test /path/to/zip /destination/folder
```

And it should work

Answer (score 1):

```
import groovy.lang.Closure;
import groovy.util.AntBuilder;
```

...

```
final AntBuilder ant = new AntBuilder();
ant.invokeMethod("echo", "copy & sync gestartet...");

ant.invokeMethod("sync", new Object[] { new HashMap<String, String>() {
  {
    this.put("todir", "./myordner2");
    this.put("verbose", "yes");
  }
}, new Closure<Object>(null) {
  @Override
  public Object call(Object... args) {
    ant.invokeMethod("fileset", new Object[] {
        new HashMap<String, String>() {
          {
            this.put("dir", "c:/myordner1/test");
          }
        }});
    return null;
  }
} });
```

I have found this solution. ;-)